# Pass multiple parameters to automapper

Tags: c#, parameters, automapper

I have a mapping between my domain object and contract as below:-

```
public class Car
{
    string name { get; set; }

    string model{ get; set; }

    CarProperties properties { get; set; }
}

public class CarProperties 
{
    string color { get; set; }

    string type { get; set; }
}

public class CarContract
{
    string name { get; set; }

    string model{ get; set; }

    string color { get; set; }

    string type { get; set; }

    string status { get; set; }
}

public static Car GetCreateCarPayloadFromCarContract(CarContract carContract, string name, ModelType modelType)
{
    var car= new Car
    {
        name = name,
        model= modelType.ToString(),
        properties = new CarProperties
        {
            color = carContract.color,
            type = carContract.type
        },
        status = Status.READY.ToString()
    };

    return car;
}
```

Here ModelType and Status are enums. I am trying to convert GetCreateCarPayloadFromCarContract method to use automapper. Below is what I have done till now. However I am not able to map name and model. How can I pass these parameters to the automapper? Also what I have done for status is that fine?

```
CreateMap<Car,CarContract>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.color, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.properties.color))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.properties.type))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.properties.color, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.color))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.properties.type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.type))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Status.READY.ToString()))
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please share the definition of `Car` and `CarContract` as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code has following observation

1. if `Properties` object is not initialized by default in
   `CarContract` class.
2. To map back the status and model you should `Enum.Parse` method.
3. The `status` always set to Ready state instead of mapped object value.

Use the below code:

```
      CreateMap<Car,CarContract>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.color, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
      src.properties.color))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
      src.properties.type))
     .ForMember(dest => dest.model, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (<<Your Model 
      Enum Type>>)Enum.Parse(typeof(<<Your Model Enum Type>>), src.model)))
     .ForMember(dest => dest.status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (<<Your Status 
      Enum Type>>)Enum.Parse(typeof(<<Your Status Enum Type>>), src.status)))
     .ReverseMap()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.properties, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new 
     CarProperties() { color = src.color, type = src.type }))
     .ForMember(dest => dest.status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.status.ToString()))
     .ForMember(dest => dest.model, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.model.ToString()))
```

> Make sure that you Replace the <> to appropriate enums.